# Loading dataframe from jupyter to dask-mpi on NERSC cluster

Tags: dask

I am attempting to load some relatively large (~15GB) VTK files into a dask dataframe using the dask-mpi client on NERSC. However, I am having a difficult time getting this to happen efficiently, with the majority of the work happening in a parallel manner on the NERSC node.

The basic structure here follows Rollin Thomas's notebook on using dask on NERSC (https://gitlab.com/NERSC/nersc-notebooks/-/tree/master/dask). So I:

1. Launch a Jupyter notebook on NERSC
2. Access a node on an interactive queue, defining a scheduler file
3. Launch a client accessing the same scheduler file. At this point I can launch the client dashboard and watch the processes
4. Read VTK file on Jupyter node, and put it into a pandas dataframe -- this works fine, requiring ~15GB of memory on the Jupyter kernel

From here, I want to load the information in the pandas dataframe to the dask client on the server, but I have not found a clean way to do so. I have tried several things:

1. Transform the pandas dataframe to a dask dataframe using from_pandas(). In this case, a lot of the memory seems to be used on the Jupyter kernel, and in fact causes an out-of-memory error on the Jupyter kernel.
2. Instead of reading the vtk file on the Jupyter kernel, make the vtk-reading function @dask.delayed, returning a single dataframe from that function. When I do this, the process happens correctly on the NERSC node, but repartitioning the dataframe uses only 1 core and so takes a long time.
3. As above, make the vtk-reading function @dask.delayed, but return a list consisting of a larger number of small pandas dataframes. In this case, the process of building the set of smaller dataframes seems to happen on the Jupyter kernel rather than the NERSC node, and so slows the processing significantly.
4. Load the vtk file on the Jupyter kernel. Then create a list indices of at which to break up the dataframe, and a function that returns the dataframe from that range of indices. Run that in from_delayed(). However, that again seems to do much of the work in the Jupyter kernel rather than the NERSC node, so runs into memory problems. Sketch below:

   ```
   vtkDF = loadVTKs()

   chunks = [[i1,j1],[i2,j2], . . .]
   for c in chunks:
       vtkDF_parts.append(foo(vtkDF,c)) #foo simply returns vtkDF from i_c->j_c

    vtkDDF = dd.from_delayed(vtkDF_parts)
    vtkDDF.persist()
   ```

I would appreciate any help anyone can provide on the best way to transfer this data into memory on the NERSC node correctly--I have been working with the folks at NERSC, but we have been unable to figure it out. Please let me know what parts of this are unclear and I will clarify--I feel like I'm just keeping my head above water on this, so am sure I'm not being completely clear.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will suit your VTK data type, but here is a way to be fairly memory conscious (dataset pulled from [https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/vtk/rbc_001.vtk](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/data/vtk/rbc_001.vtk)):

```
import meshio
import dask.dataframe as dd

mesh_data = meshio.vtk.read('rbc_100.vtk')
num_per_partition = 100
df = dd.from_array(mesh_data.cells[0][1:][0], num_per_partition)
```

You can also use the vtk package and do the same thing essentially (for poly data).  Nothing will be loaded in memory in the dask DataFrame until you do a compute cycle.  Let me know if this helps or if you have any questions.

Edit:

Sorry for not getting back to you sooner.  So pandas (I'm assuming geopandas if you're doing spatial operations) is not very good with memory management.  I don't know what kind of spatial filtering you are trying to do, but perhaps exploring different libraries for more memory efficient operations could be helpful.  Is your file in ASCII format?  I'm assuming you are using vtk or meshio, you may have a better time parsing the data yourself with pure io and splitting the data up in to parquet files which both dask and pandas can read.  (Cells, points etc.) This will allow you to limit the amount of data that is read.  Also, that way you can load the vtk in to a dask data frame lazily, process, save to disk, and then load in geopandas instead of exchanging the data in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I'm not sure this really addresses my problem, as it's not clear how it addresses loading the data from the jupyter interface to the dask-mpi client on the cluster. For somewhat smaller datasets the dd.from_pandas() approach (#1 in my list of approaches above) works, but once there are 700M rows in the dataframe this runs into an out-of-memory error on the juypter kernel. I could try to transform from the dataframe to an array to save memory (though I need to transform back to a dataframe for later spatial filtering)--let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Saving the VTKs as Parquet files to be loaded is my current solution--I was hoping to avoid that, as it adds another step and takes a while, but I can make that work to load the data in memory. That takes me to a different set of memory problems, but I'll put it in a separate Stack Overflow question since it has to do with memory solely on the NERSC node. 
I do use geopandas because I need to do a spatial join, for which I haven't seen good alternatives. But I'm trying to do that within dask so that I'm doing it on a smaller data subset. 
Thanks for your help!